# Creating a "New" button that opens a new JFrame

Tags: java, swing

So im working on a database form for employees. I have a "new" button that is supposed to open a new JFrame where you would enter your information and then click save to update the database.

So I have a JFrame called "workers". This displays all the information from the database. You can go through each employee and see their information using the next and previous buttons.

Then I have a new JFrame called "New_Entry". Here you can enter in information and click "Save" which the adds a new entry into the database.

On the "Workers" JFrame I have created a button that called "New" which is supposed to bring up the "New_Entry" JFrame for you to create a new entry.

Below you can see the code I created for the "New" button, but Im not sure if its correct.
Reason being because on the "New_Entry" JFrame when I click on the "Save" button I get a Nullpointerexception and I think it's because of my "New" button. I think the cursor is getting lost when  I click on the "New" button and I need some code that points the cursor to the "New_Entry" JFrame when I click on the "New" button. Is there a code line that i need to insert that points the cursor to the new JFrame?

Code for the "new" button:

```
private void btnNewActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       

    try
    {
      curRow = rs.getRow();

    }

    catch (SQLException err)
    {
        System.out.println(err.getMessage());
    }


      java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
        new New_Entry().setVisible(true);
    }
     });
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: To get help you need to inbclude more code. It's currently not possible to help you.

Comment: To simplify I am just asking how do I code a button that opens a new JFrame. This new JFrame will be one that has text fields to input data and save it to the database

Comment: 1) you should NOT be creating a new JFrame. An application should only have a single JFrame. For other windows you can use a JDialog. 2) You create a JDialog the same way you create a JFrame. You create an instance of the JDialog. You create components and add them to a JPanel. Then you add the panel to the dialog.

Comment: Amazing, thank you very much for the input @camickr